# Prove that the derivative of an even differentiable function is odd, and the derivative of an odd differentiable function is even.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Prove that the derivative of an even differentiable function is odd, and the derivative of an odd differentiable function is even.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried, and what prevented you from getting the answer?

Comment: Can you give some context or attempt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $f$ is even: $$\begin{align*} f'(-x) & = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(-x + h) - f(-x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{h} =  \\ & = -\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h} = -f'(x) \end{align*}$$

If $f$ is odd: $$\begin{align*} f'(-x) & = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(-x + h) - f(-x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{-f(x - h) + f(x)}{h} =  \\ & = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h} = f'(x) \end{align*}$$

Comment: How ioss the last line of "If f is even" equal to -f'(x)?

Answer (score 6):

$f$ is even : $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Example: $f(x) =x^2$.

Differentiate both sides:

$-f'(-x) = f'(x)$, chain rule,

or $f'(-x) = -f'(x).$

2) $f$ is odd: $f(-x) = - f(x)$.

Example: $f(x) = x^3$.

Differentiate both sides:

$-f'(-x) = -f'(x)$, chain rule,

or $f'(-x)= f'(x)$.

Comment: Very nice application of chain rule!

Answer (score 2):

We will prove that, the derivative of an odd function is even
Suppose f is an odd function
Therefore  f(-x) = - f(x) , for every x in R

Taking Derivatives of both the sides with respect to x , we get
              d/dx f(-x) =  d/dx [-f(x)]

Using chain Rule , we get,
       f'(-x).d/dx (-x) = - f'(x)

i.e        f'(-x) .(-1) = - f'(x)
Therefore      - f'(-x) = - f'(x)  , cancelling -ve signs from both the sides,
we get           f'(-x) =  f'(x) , for all x in R
 This proves that, f is an even function.

Similarly we can prove that, the derivative of an even function is odd